# Is there any intersection find algorithm similar to union find when sets are not disjoint?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, computer-science

I want to find intersection of sets containing integer values?
What is the most efficient way to do it if say you have 4-5 lists with 2k-4k integers?

Comment: In python you can use a `set`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computing set intersection in linear time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642172/computing-set-intersection-in-linear-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***If*** you have memory to spare:

- Create a set that will hold the number of occurences of each value.
- For each integer I in each of your set, increment the number of occurences of I
- Extract integers with a number of occurences equal to the number of sets

This is theoretically in O(sum of all sets cardinalities + retrieval)

where `retrieveal` can be either the range of your integers (if you're using a raw array) or the cardinality of the union of your sets (if you're using a hash table to enumerate the values for which an occurence is defined).

If the bounds of your set are known and small, you can implement it with a simple array of integers big enough to hold the max number of sets (typically a 8 bits char for 256 sets).

Otherwise you'll need some kind of hash table, which should still theoretically be in o(n).

Answer (score 1):

In many languages like for example c++ sets are implemented as balanced binary trees so you can directly evaluate set intersection in `O(NlogM)` use n as smaller set size by just looking up into the other set in `O(logM)`.

**Optimization :-**

As you want it for multiple sets you can do the optimization that is used in `huffman coding` :-

> 1. Use a priority queue of sets which selects smallest set first
> 2. select two smallest sets first evaluate intersection and add it to queue.
> 3. Do this till you get empty intersection set or one set(intersection set) remaining.

**Note:** Use std::set if using c++